# Getting audio files buffer for web audio visualization

Tags: javascript, audio, web, visualization

I'm trying to audio visualization.
using this web audio js [pizzicato](https://alemangui.github.io/pizzicato/#sound-from-waveform) for load files,
and this code for [visualization](https://github.com/Raathigesh/HTML5AudioVisualizer)
I want to get the loaded files buffer and input buffer to start() method.

```
AudioVisualizer.prototype.start = function(buffer) {
  this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(buffer, decodeAudioDataSuccess,
        decodeAudioDataFailed);
  var that = this;

  function decodeAudioDataSuccess(decodedBuffer) {
      that.sourceBuffer.buffer = decodedBuffer
      that.sourceBuffer.start(0);
  }
}
```

How can get the files buffer?
or
How can get sound buffer about current output?

Comment: Your visualization code already has a built-in way to load files (change [this line](https://github.com/Raathigesh/HTML5AudioVisualizer/blob/master/scripts/Site.js#L164) to load from a different url). Also, in your code, you already have the file's decoded audioBuffer (`decodedBuffer`), and the raw file buffer (`buffer`). If you need to read the current output of your audioContext, use a [ScriptProcessorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ScriptProcessorNode), but it's really unclear what you want from your question.

Comment: I want to play many types of sound files at the same time or at different times, and visualize them. In this code, if I load more than one file, it will fail due to a buffer set problem :-(